# How to submit app access credentials in play console for google sign in feature

Tags: android, credentials, review

I submited the app for review on play console and they rejected it because of Play Console Requirements Policy

Check Rejection Email Below:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tscoz.png

I uses google singnin authentication feature so there is no need of username and password we can login directly using google account but they are demanding this credentials

What should i do now to review my app

Comment: What if user doesn't have Google account? Don't you want them to login?

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar problem in one of the apps that had only Google Sign-in.

Even though we use Google Sign-in, I believe it's still required to declare that your app's functionality is restricted behind any type of Login.

You do not need to provide the "credentials" in case of Google Sign-in, but you still need to give instructions about this.

So, from Google Play Console, for your app,

1. Go to App Content -> App Access -> Manage.
2. Select "All or some functionality is restricted"
3. Click "Add new instruction". It'll open a form with 4 fields - "Name", "Username/phone number", "Password", "Any other instruction".
4. You can write "Google Login" as Name field.
5. Keep username and password fields blank.
6. If your app asks for any additional information when a new user signs in through Google, give the dummy values for those fields as part of "Any other instruction" field.

Just for example - if a new user user downloads the app and do sign-in, if your app first asks that enter your father's name before accessing other features of the app, then you need to provide that dummy value as part of "Any other instruction" field.

Another big thing to note here - when you upload your bundle to Google Play and if you've enabled signing by Google, your release SHA1 key changes, so make sure your Google Sign-in works in the build that's uploaded on console. If it's not working, your app will be rejected again.